# Manipulating Direct Query Data Sources

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a direct query data source - Due to it being DQ, I am unable to use query editor - Any manipulation must be done through DAX formulas.

What I'm trying to achieve:
I need to subtract each row in TABLEA.ColA against the values in TABLEB

What I have tried:

I have **TABLE A - Direct Query Data Source**:

```
ID| ColA | ColB |
-----------------
A |   1  |   4  |
B |   2  |   5  |
C |   3  |   6  |
```

I have **TABLE B - A manually entered table**:

```
ID| ColX |
----------
A |   12 |
B |   13 |
C |   14 |
```

I attempted making a new column in TABLE A which used *lookupvalue* to map values from TABLEB.ColX onto TABLEA's ID's

Unfortunately lookupvalue for column manipulation is not allowed with DQ either.

QUESTION: How can I manually add a custom column of predefined values into TABLEA (a DQ data source)?

Comment: can you use a relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with **Measure** instead of **Calculated Column**  as below using **LOOKUPVALUE**-

```
lookup_value = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    table_b[ColX],
    table_b[ID],MIN(table_a[id])
)
```

Here is the output-

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the only accessible tags from TABLEA are other measures. Which means I cannot access TABLEA's ID column..

Comment: Share the code you are trying with now if possible.